# change application background through a button

Tags: android

i want to set a different background color to all application activities through a click on a button, but at now i ve done it only for one activity and i can't do it for all activities. this is the rude code:

```
    optionlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.optionlayout);
    backgroundbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backgroundbutton);
    int counter = 0;

    backgroundbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (counter ==0) {
                optionlayout.setBackgroundColor(0xFF5774B3);
                counter++;
            }else if (counter == 1){
                optionlayout.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0CC258);
                counter++;
            } else if (counter==2){
                optionlayout.setBackgroundColor(0xCC000000);
                counter++;
            }else if (counter== 3){
                optionlayout.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    });
```

i want to change the

```
    optionlayout.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0CC258);
```

with an action that changes the background in all activities permanently. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use shared preferences and store your counter there, and in onCreate of activities first look in your shared preferences to determine what color to set your background.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There's no way to change a property of a whole application through an activity. You can create a custom class that extends `Activity` and implements `OnClickListener`.
Something like that:

```
class MyCustomActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //your code inside onClick()
    }
}
```

And then you can extend your activities to this one, for example:

```
class MainActivity extends MyCustomActivity { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the extras method.

Pass the changes on from activity to activity maybe it helps.

Its a longer process to set up your page each time but i don't see any other way. I'm still open to suggestions

```
// you can have multiple extras.
String bgColor = "yourColor";
Intent newIntent = new Intent(thisActivity.this, theNextActivity.class); 
// Start new activity
        dispatchIntent.putExtra("bgColor", bgColor);
// Send color to new activity

        startActivity(newIntent);
        finish();

// Get the background color in the new page
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String bgColor = extras.getString("bgColor");

// The trick is to get the string into your background color format such as
0xFF5774B3
```